# Create an optimization problem with python pulp to minimize two summations

Tags: python, sum, minimize, pulp

I need to create a minimizing problem in order to minimize this function:

∑_i(Disp i *Ho)   +  Co*∑_iWi

The main task is to fill the the following table with the optimal values with initial values equal to zero.

```
# table to replicate ################################
#               set-21 ott-21 nov-21 dec-21 gen-21
# Qi              0       0     0      0      0
# Wi              0       0     0      0      0
# Qai             0       0     0      0      0
# Disp_i          0       0     0      0      0
#########################################################
```

The main problem is that the other two variables not mentioned in the object function need to be optimized due to some constraints where they are involved.

Disp_i can go from -inf to +inf.
Wi is a binary (0,1).
h0 and c0 are costants.
the other constants are specified in the attached code.

I've tried to solve the problem using scipy but I couldn't figure it out.
I then tried with pulp but I still can't figure it out.

This is the code I have written so far. It seems quite well written to me but I keep getting some errors.

```
import numpy as np
from pulp import *

# table to replicate ################################
#               set-21 ott-21 nov-21 dec-21 gen-21
# Qi              0       0     0      0      0
# Wi              0       0     0      0      0
# Qai             0       0     0      0      0
# Disp_i          0       0     0      0      0
#########################################################

#lists (table columns)
temp_int = ["set-21", "ott-21", "nov-21", "dec-21", "gen-21"]

#dictionaries
D_i = {"set-21": 3255,
       "ott-21": 3241,
       "nov-21": 2634,
       "dec-21": 3292,
       "gen-21": 3287}

# transp = {"Qi": {"set-21": 0, "ott-21": 0, "nov-21": 0, "dec-21": 0, "gen-21": 0},
#           "Wi": {"set-21": 0, "ott-21": 0, "nov-21": 0, "dec-21": 0, "gen-21": 0},
#           "Qai": {"set-21": 0, "ott-21": 0, "nov-21": 0, "dec-21": 0, "gen-21": 0},
#           "Disp_i": {"set-21": 0, "ott-21": 0, "nov-21": 0, "dec-21": 0, "gen-21": 0}
#           }

# define
h0 = 0.005596951
c0 = 32.1
arrot = 275
M = 10000000
lotMin = 3300
Disp_0 = 2286

# set problem variable
prob = LpProblem("Supply_Chain", LpMinimize)

# decision variables
Qi_var = LpVariable.dicts("Decision_Variables", temp_int, lowBound=0, cat=LpInteger)
Wi_var = LpVariable.dicts("Wi", temp_int, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)
Qai_var = LpVariable.dicts("Qai", temp_int, lowBound=0, cat=LpInteger)
Disp_1_var = LpVariable.dicts("Disp_i", temp_int, lowBound=-np.inf, cat=LpInteger)

# objective function
prob += h0*lpSum(Disp_1_var[i] for i in temp_int) + c0*lpSum(Wi_var[i] for i in temp_int)

# constraints
for i in temp_int:
    prob += Qi_var[i] >= lotMin * Wi_var[i]

for i in temp_int:
    prob += arrot*Qai_var[i] == Qi_var[i]

#for i in temp_int:
    prob += lpSum(Qi_var[i] for i in temp_int) >= lpSum(D_i[i] for i in temp_int)

for i in temp_int:
    prob += Disp_1_var[i] >= 0

for i in temp_int:
    prob += Qi_var[i] <= M*Wi_var[i]

for i in temp_int:
    prob += Qi_var[i] >= Wi_var[i]

for i in temp_int:
    if i == 0:
        Disp_1_var[i] = Disp_0 + Qi_var[i] - D_i[i]
    else:
        Disp_1_var[i] = Disp_0 + Qi_var[i] - D_i[i]  # Disp_1_var[i-1]

prob.solve()
print("Status: ", LpStatus[prob.status])

for i in temp_int:
     print(Qi_var[i].varValue)
     print(Disp_1_var[i].varValue)
```

This is the output I get:

```
C:\Python\Python395\python.exe C:/Users/davide.tamagnini.con/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2021.1/scratches/example.py
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.9.0 
Build Date: Feb 12 2015 

command line - C:\Python\Python395\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\..\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe C:\Users\DAVIDE~1.CON\AppData\Local\Temp\f262fcfe1f714303af02b97868f3a9a5-pulp.mps branch printingOptions all solution C:\Users\DAVIDE~1.CON\AppData\Local\Temp\f262fcfe1f714303af02b97868f3a9a5-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 35 COLUMNS
At line 156 RHS
At line 187 BOUNDS
Bad image at line 193 <  LO BND       X0000005  -inf >
Bad image at line 194 <  LO BND       X0000006  -inf >
Bad image at line 195 <  LO BND       X0000007  -inf >
Bad image at line 196 <  LO BND       X0000008  -inf >
Bad image at line 197 <  LO BND       X0000009  -inf >
At line 208 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 30 rows, 20 columns and 70 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 5 errors
There were 5 errors on input
** Current model not valid
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
** Current model not valid
No match for C:\Users\DAVIDE~1.CON\AppData\Local\Temp\f262fcfe1f714303af02b97868f3a9a5-pulp.sol - ? for list of commands
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.01   (Wallclock seconds):       0.01

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\davide.tamagnini.con\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2021.1\scratches\example.py", line 73, in <module>
    prob.solve()
  File "C:\Python\Python395\lib\site-packages\pulp\pulp.py", line 1737, in solve
    status = solver.actualSolve(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python395\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\coin_api.py", line 101, in actualSolve
    return self.solve_CBC(lp, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python395\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\coin_api.py", line 159, in solve_CBC
    raise PulpSolverError("Pulp: Error while executing "+self.path)
pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing C:\Python\Python395\lib\site-packages\pulp\apis\..\solverdir\cbc\win\64\cbc.exe

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any suggetion is heartily accepted.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and why isn't it working?  Your question is to vague to get a good answer and the platform is intended to help with coding issues, not develop a solution for you from scratch...  Suggest you edit your question with a reproducible example and explanation of why it isn't working.

Comment: You're right, excuse me. I'm quite new to the community. I edited the question. I hope it's more uderstandable now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  You've got your work cut out for you.  :)  No offense, but this is a *complete* train wreck.  Let me give you a couple things to start with.  My overall suggestion is to start very small (no constraints) and just get something that builds and solves, even if it is nonsense, and slowly build up rather than trying to code the whole thing at once, which is tougher to troubleshoot.

Issues:

1. Don't import `numpy`.  Save that for later.  Your model has a fatal error in this:

   Disp_1_var = LpVariable.dicts("Disp_i", temp_int, lowBound=-np.inf, cat=LpInteger)

`numpy` negative infinity is not valid in pulp.  And what value is it anyway?  Just forget about this lower bound

2. This *might* be valid, I'm not sure, but it is useless:

   prob += arrot*Qai_var[i] == Qi_var[i]

if `x*5 = y`, then you only have one variable, kill the other.

3. I'm not sure this is valid:

   lpSum(Qi_var[i] for i in temp_int) >= lpSum(D_i[i] for i in temp_int)

rewrite it such that you only have one lpSum with a little algebra...

4. When will `temp_int` be zero?  and why name something `temp_int`?  :)  And you **cannot** assign a variable like this, you need to make constraint.

   for i in temp_int:

   ```
   if i == 0:
       Disp_1_var[i] = Disp_0 + Qi_var[i] - D_i[i]
   else:
       Disp_1_var[i] = Disp_0 + Qi_var[i] - D_i[i]  # Disp_1_var[i-1]
   ```

Lots of fixes.  I recommend starting from scratch and introduce 1 small piece at time...